# ASP.NET MVC Form Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
   <form action="/Villa/Add" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBox("name") %>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Name") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

My form is above, how do I retrieve the values in my controller?

Thanks a lot in advance! Hard to find the right material because of different Previews of MVC being released and being different.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This works for ASP.Net MVC Beta.

```
 public ActionResult Add( string name ) {
    ....
 }

 or

 public ActionResult Add( FormCollection form ) {
      string name = form["Name"];
 }

 or

 public ActionResult Add( [Bind(Prefix="")]Villa villa ) {
       villa.Name ...
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried something like this?  Pseudocode...

```
public class VillaController : Controller 
{
      public ActionResult Add(string name)
      {
          // Code...
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It belongs to your url routes, you defined.

In your case the form ist looking for an controller named "Villa" and the action inside of it named "Add".

Maybe you should read ScottGu's blog post: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/02/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios.aspx