# What is the best practice for mvc2 confirm password field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have asked a similar question recently but getting no answers i am taking a step back with a more broad approach.

I am looking to create a confirm password field using asp.net MVC2 that works on the client.  All my other client validation is done with MicrosoftMvcValidation.js by just adding the Html.EnableClientValidation(); call.

Some of my considerations.  Should the confirm password be part of the model object?  Using that approach i have created server side validation by creating my own model binder.

Are there any projects out there that have done this?

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea about password confirmation:

We sign up to hundreds of sites, and it amazing that almost all of them force us to
confirm password. 
This doesn’t make any sense. 
For sure you give users a way to reset their passwords, so what is the point of confirming it? 
If someone forgets it or had a typo in it (which is rare anyway), then (s)he just resets the password. 
Personally, I feel that password confirmation is a waste of time and resources and **is not very user-friendly.**
(there is not any password confirmation in most of new site, like facebook, etc...)

Comment: +1 I came here to say this, I read something recently (a blog maybe?) that was discussing all of the unnecessary pains that users are put through without getting any added benefit. This type of thing is a perfect example of what it was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The confirm password should definitely not be part of the model object. There is no need to store it. And I can't see why you need a custom model binder, either?

Just have two password fields. One will be the real password you store, the other will be a dummy field that is just used for confirmation. You then just check in your controller (or wherever) that the two passwords match. It's not something that needs to be complex.

Comment: If the field is not mart of the model, how would this information reach the controller?

Comment: Your controller could accept a string with the same name as the confirm password field or you could get it from the FormCollection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317225/asp-net-mvc-form-post