# My MVC Create View tries to insert into my db even before I can see the form to input values for the insert

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

my Create page is basically a form that's hardcoded to match arguments in an insert statement thats part of my QuestionModel. My codes are as follows :

```
        public string Create(int Poll_ID, int User_ID, int QuestionGroup, int QuestionType, string Text, int PartialAnswers, int Max, int QOrder, string DataType)
    {
        //int Permission = CheckPermissionMethod(Poll_ID, User_ID); //user permission id
        int Permission = 3;
        string Result; // message shown to user
        int MaxQuestion_ID;
        OleDbDataReader OleDbDataReader;
        OleDbDataReader myOleDbDataReader;
        if (Permission == 3)
        {
            if (QuestionGroup < 3) //MCQ or Participant List Question
            {
                //get the maximum question id
                OleDbDataReader = DBConn("SELECT MAX(Question_ID) \"Question_ID\" FROM MCQ_QUESTIONS");
                OleDbDataReader.Read();
                MaxQuestion_ID = Convert.ToInt32(OleDbDataReader["Question_ID"]) + 1;

            myOleDbConnection.Close();
            Result = "Question was added to your poll! ";
        }
        else
            Result = "You are not permitted to create a question.";
        return Result;
    }
```

This is part of my QuestionModel under my models.

```
         <% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Question", FormMethod.Post)) { %>
     <% if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) ViewData["ErrorMessage"])) { %>
          Poll_Id: <%= Html.TextBox("Poll_Id")%><br />
      User_Id: <%= Html.TextBox("User_Id")%><br />
      QuestionGroup: <%= Html.TextBox("QuestionGroup")%><br />
      QuestionType: <%= Html.TextBox("QuestionType")%><br />
      Text: <%= Html.TextBox("Text")%><br />
      PartialAnswers: <%= Html.TextBox("PartialAnswers")%><br />
      Max: <%= Html.TextBox("Max")%><br />
      QOrder: <%= Html.TextBox("QOrder")%><br />
      DataType: <%= Html.TextBox("DataType")%><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

My Question Controller is as follows :

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        QuestionModel Question = new QuestionModel();
        int Poll_Id = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Poll_Id"]);
        int User_Id = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["User_Id"]);
        int QuestionGroup = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["QuestionGroup"]);
        int QuestionType = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["QuestionType"]);
        string Text = Convert.ToString(TempData["Text"]);
        int PartialAnswers = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["PartialAnswers"]);
        int Max = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Max"]);
        int QOrder = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["QOrder"]);
        string DataType = Convert.ToString(TempData["DataType"]);

        Question.Create(Poll_Id, User_Id, QuestionGroup, QuestionType, Text, PartialAnswers, Max, QOrder, DataType);



        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Submit()
    {
        TempData["Poll_Id"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Poll_Id"]);
        TempData["User_Id"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["User_Id"]);
        TempData["QuestionGroup"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["QuestionGroup"]);
        TempData["QuestionType"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["QuestionType"]);
        TempData["Text"] = Request.Form["Text"];
        TempData["PartialAnswers"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["PartialAnswers"]);
        TempData["Max"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Max"]);
        TempData["QOrder"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["QOrder"]);
        TempData["DataType"] = Request.Form["DataType"];
        //return RedirectToAction("Create");
        ViewData["Poll_Id"] = "Setting the values";
        return View();
     }

    }
```

My first routes entry is as follows :

```
            routes.MapRoute(
           "Question",                                              // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Question", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
       );
```

I just want to be able to see my html form, enter values, click on submit, and the page creates and inserts the entry into my MCQ_Questions table accordingly. Any help is much appreciated guys!

Answer (score 1):

How you would normally achieve this is by

- having two separate `Create` actions
- decorate one with `[HttpGet]`. In here you just return the view with a default model
- decorate the other with `[HttpPost]`. Here you insert to database and return `Display` action if validation passes otherwise return view with errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to make ViewModel for create as a class.

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
public int Poll_id = {get ; set;}
//...
}

//View would look like (inherits from CreateViewModel)
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Poll_id) %>

//Controller
public ActionResult Create()
{
CreateViewModel newCreateView= new CreateViewModel();
return View(newCreateView);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel newCreateView)
{
//Put code to save all into database here
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

It will sumbit your data after writing them in the view.

Comment: was just looking at your post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317225/asp-net-mvc-form-post Actually I'm using Oracle, those models seem to be for microsoft sql, mysql etc. Is there a workaround?

Comment: This is just another Mariusz :) and article is for MVC 1 and as I can see you are working on MVC2 or MVC3.

Comment: You can find answer for that on this forum. Just type mvc and oracle it shows many subjects with your question.